# Store Kit ругается после обновления Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

Store Kit ругается после обновления Xcode на 7 версию.
Проект на Swift, работали встроенные покупки IOS

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does not conform to protocol обычно значит, что один из обязательных методов протокола пропущен. Поскольку в `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` всего один такой метод, видимо его и не хватает: `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)`.

Насчет второй ошибки не уверен, [знающие люди говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460472/objective-c-method-conflicts-with-optional-requirement-method-swift) надо удалить название метода и напечатать заново.

Comment: Да, все правильно, немного изменился синтаксис в этом методе: paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])      старый вариант который не работал в xcode 7:      paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)